# In Flutter how can I receive an image in a main screen and then redirect it to another screen?

Tags: image, flutter

I'm developing a Card Game where the user can add new cards. Each card has an image path.
I'm trying to prefill my New Card screen with an image that comes from another app (ex: Gallery).
For this I'm using package [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent), having successfully managed to print to console my image path within my app. Now what I can't do is to redirect to new screen after getting my image.
Here is the relevant code from my home screen:

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  Menu({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  StreamSubscription _intentDataStreamSubscription;
  List<SharedMediaFile> _sharedFiles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bootstrapCards();
    getOurCards();
    // For sharing images coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory
    _intentDataStreamSubscription = ReceiveSharingIntent.getMediaStream()
        .listen((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles = value;
        print("Shared:" + (_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));
        _goCardAdd((_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));

      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getIntentDataStream error: $err");
    });

    // For sharing images coming from outside the app while the app is closed
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialMedia().then((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles = value;
        print("Shared:" + (_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));
        _goCardAdd((_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));

      });
    });

  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _intentDataStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  void _goCardAdd(path) {
    MyCard myEmptyCard = new MyCard();
    myEmptyCard.url=path;
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AddEditScreen(myCard: myEmptyCard)),
    );
  }
```

It seems that the _goCardAdd call isn't doing anything and I cannot understand why.
And if I put it after the setState call then I get an error saying

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

The complete code can be found at https://github.com/diogocsc/papoapapoFlutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it might have been some kind of build issue, as i have only made minor changes to the code and it started working. Meanwhile I needed to add an if clause to check if the file is there, because if not, it would always redirect me to the new card screen when I opened my app, even if no image file was underway. Check the code below.

```
class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  StreamSubscription _intentDataStreamSubscription;
  List<SharedMediaFile> _sharedFiles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    bootstrapCards();
    // For sharing images coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory
    _intentDataStreamSubscription = ReceiveSharingIntent.getMediaStream()
        .listen((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles = value;
        print("Shared 1:" + (_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));
        if (_sharedFiles != null) _goCardAdd((_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));

      });

    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getIntentDataStream error: $err");
    });

    // For sharing images coming from outside the app while the app is closed
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialMedia().then((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedFiles = value;
        print("Shared 2:" + (_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));
        if (_sharedFiles != null) _goCardAdd((_sharedFiles?.map((f) => f.path)?.join(",") ?? ""));

      });

    });
```